# Angularjs Callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently having an issue with populating some textareas with text. When I step through with the debugger it works fine, however when I let it run normally it will only populate the fields with the data on the second time it is loaded. This leads me to believe that the issue is to do with how the page is loading. I am trying to delay the execution of my method that attempts to populate the fields using callbacks however I am completely new to this method of programming in JS, let alone AngularJS.

I keep getting the `Callback is not a function` error whenever I try this :

```
 $scope.StudyAndUnderstandingContent = []
$http.post('url', {stepNumber: currentStep.currentstep})
.then(function success(response, getCallback) {
    $scope.StudyAndUnderstandingContent = response.data.step;
    getCallback();
});
```

And here is my callback function:

```
function getCallback()
{
    $http.post('url2', getData)
    .then(function(response)
    {
        angular.forEach(response.data.answer, function(value, key)
        {
            $scope.answers.push(response.data.answer[key]); 
        });

        $scope.textBoxes = [];
        angular.forEach(angular.element($(".inline-q")), function(value, key)
        {
            $scope.textBoxes.push(value);
            $scope.textBoxes[key].value = $scope.answers[key].answer;
        });
    });
}
```

I have looked at the other questions whilst also trying to find my own fix, but I have made 0 progress. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is it outside of angular's `$scope`?

Comment: Without traceing your codw just a quick thought...   you probably need to wait for the page to load completely...

Comment: do you mean `getCallback is not a function`?

Comment: it's sitting inside of the controller, so it shouldn't be a reference issue, I use this method elsewhere in the code and it works fine, I might move the method outside of the controller and pass it in and see if that works.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney yes, I was generalising, sorry.

Comment: @me_ that's what I'm thinking, I'm hoping this will fix it, but it's a new concept

Comment: I don't know angular but there is a built in for javascript onload event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to pass callback function in success

```
$scope.StudyAndUnderstandingContent = []
$http.post('url', {stepNumber: currentStep.currentstep})
.then(function success(response) {
    $scope.StudyAndUnderstandingContent = response.data.step;
    getCallback();
});
```

See the document for [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks a tonne! Can't believe I didn't think to do this straight away.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $http.post('url', {stepNumber: currentStep.currentstep}).then(

        function successCallback(response) {
          $scope.StudyAndUnderstandingContent = response.data.step;
          getCallback();
        },
        function errorCallback (response) {
         // handle error
        }
      );
```

Comment: this was correct but @Gaurav answered first, thanks anyways :)

Comment: no problem but you can appreciate the effort by giving up vote to gourov :)  @geolaw